# Onde colocar a tag string nem como colocar da foma correta o ID

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, eu gostaria da ajuda de você, pois não consigo organizar o código, ele sozinho pega porém quando implemento ele nesta página ai, não funciona. oque poderia mudar?

Código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Version</title>
</head>
<body onload="loadVersion()">
<div>
<div id="802470398582881273" align="center" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: 
hidden;" class="wcustomhtml">
    Versão :<font id="file1" size="4" color="#515151"></font>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            //declaração da função JS
            function loadVersion() {
                // ALTERAR ENDEREÇO DO ARQUIVO

$.getJSON('http://teccitystore.com.br/downloads/files_versions.json', 
function(json) {
                    var objs = [[], [], []];
                    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
                        objs[i] = json[i];
                    }
                    //SETANDO OS VALORES - PEGA ID E PASSA O VALOR DO JSON
                    var file1 = document.getElementById("file1").innerHTML = 
objs[0].filename+ "&nbsp;-&nbsp;v" + objs[0].version;
                    //var file2 = document.getElementById("file2").innerHTML = objs[1].filename+ "&nbsp;-&nbsp;v" + objs[1].version;
                    //var file3 = document.getElementById("file3").innerHTML = objs[2].filename+ "&nbsp;-&nbsp;v" + objs[2].version;            
                });
            };

        </script>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Você não está chamando a função.

Comment: Eu chamei ela no começo do código no body, com o "onload"